# PECL extension in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: php, mediawiki, ubuntu

while setting up [mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org) on my local development machine, the installer told me that since i do not have PECL extension to php installed, i will have to do with slower page load speeds with traditional php page loading.

Does PECL really increase page load speeds?

How do i install it on my Ubuntu LAMP server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was the message you saw something like this?

> "**Warning**: The [intl PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/intl) is not available to handle Unicode normalization, falling back to slow pure-PHP implementation.
>   If you run a high-traffic site, you should read a little on [Unicode normalization](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Unicode_normalization_considerations)."

What it's telling you is that you should install the [intl extension](http://pecl.php.net/intl) from PECL; otherwise MediaWiki will have to use its own Unicode normalization code, which is slow.

On Ubuntu, this extension is available as the [php5-intl package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/php5-intl).

Answer (score 2):

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

for install on PHP 7.2 & Ubuntu 18.04 run this command:

```
sudo apt install php-intl
```

Comment: pecl can improve your system, but not necessarily, it depends in your code, the whole process of the page, the cacheability of components and many more things. It will be better to ask about specific problems when you face them.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer as to why PECL will affect your page load times. But regarding the installation of PECL to your PHP installation Google is your friend.

I found this link [How to install a PHP PECL extension/module on Ubuntu](http://www.mkfoster.com/2009/01/04/how-to-install-a-php-pecl-extensionmodule-on-ubuntu/)